# How do i modify my IllegalArgumentException to include negative values?

Tags: java, illegalargumentexception

The question statement:

> Write a method called getGrade that accepts an integer representing a
>   student's grade in a course and returns that student's numerical
>   course grade. The grade can be between 0.0 (failing) and 4.0
>   (perfect). Assume that scores are in the range of 0 to 100 and that
>   grades are based on the following scale: and make the method throw an
>   IllegalArgumentException if the user passes a grade lower than 0 or
>   higher than 100.

It works for everything but negative values...
so if the user input -1 its giving me 0.0 rather than an error.

Here is my code:

```
public double getGrade(int score) {
   double grade = 0;
   if(score<60) {
     grade = 0.0;
     return grade;
   } else if (score>=60 && score<=62) {
         grade = 0.7;
      return grade;
   } else if (score>=63 && score<95) {
         grade = (0.7+(0.1*(score-62)));
      return grade;
   } else if (score>=95 && score<100) {
         grade = 4.0;
      return grade;
   } else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }
}
```

Comment: negative 1 is < 60, so it assigns 0 to grade and returns at line 5.

Comment: Change if(score<60) to if(score<60 && score > 0) {

Comment: Thanks a lot Siddhartha!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to modify `if(score<60) {` to `if(score>=0 && score<60) {`.